# how to exclude classes from an ear fileset in ant script jacoco report

Tags: ant, war, ear, jacoco

I m trying to  generate a coverage report from a webapp.

I am using Jacoco + Ant to script de report generation.

I am able to set my ear by this code and want to exclude some classes which are in double:

```
<fileset dir="foo.ear">
  <exclude name="org/jboss/osgi/framework/main/**/AbstractPackageAttribute*.*"/>
</fileset>
```

I tried to put  tags, but it still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

For the Instrumentation you can use:

```
    <jacoco:instrument destdir="${result.classes.instr.dir}">
           <zipfileset src="${result.classes.dir}/package_bundle.jar">      
                   <include name="**"/>
                   <exclude name="**/bin/tmp/*.class"/>
          </zipfileset>
    </jacoco:instrument>
```

()This means include all the classes from the .jar file that is specified in "zipfileset" tag.
): specifies any prefixed package name.

For the jacoco:report:

```
<structure name="JaCoCo Ant Test">  
         ---------------------Other USeful stuff like "executiondata, rule"------------
     <classfiles> 
        <zipfileset src="${result.classes.dir}/package_bundle.jar"> 
            <include name="**"/>
            <exclude name="**/bin/tmp/*.class"/>
        </zipfileset>

        ---------------------Other USeful stuff like "executiondata, rule"--------------
     </classfiles>
```

Explanation is done once for the instrumentation tag.